# Resource Files not being Compiled into DLLs

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, resources, resx

I have a localized WinForms application. To avoid a large number of iterations in the translation procedure, I have given our translators software to allow them to edit the .resx files directly.

This has worked great for the resource files that are not tied to UI components (Forms/Controls), but for forms and Controls the resources don't seem to be getting updated. What I mean by this, is that at design-time all resource strings are correct (Text/ToolTips et al.) and I can see the correct translations - when I run the application (debug or any other release) the translations are not being updated, why?

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit1. The plot thickens further. There are two buttons that are not being updated at all when I change their components (button text, tooltip or any thing governed by the underlying resource file). Lets say I change the button text from 'Lock Workbook' to 'Lock Workbook GG', then the new text shows in the designer and the .resx files (both in the .resx designer and the code behind) but when I run the code (in debug or release mode) the button text is not updated!?

If I update the button next to the button I updated above, this does change the text in the running application?? This is baking my noodle as I fail to see where the old text is being stored and why for a sub-set of buttons their component text is not getting updated!?

Any ideas are warmly welcomed!

---

Edit2. I have tried to delete the .suo and clean and recompile. I have also removed the troublesome form from the solution and re added it.

So that you can see this strange behavior, here is one of the problematic buttons ('Lock Workbook GG') and a normal one ('Set as Default Workbook GG').

[image: DesignTime]

Now at run-time I see

[image: RunTime]

Comment: Just out of curiosity how do you set the properties (text, tooltip, and so on) of the buttons? What resource files do you have in the final project output directory - i assume only the resources dll? And last question - what are the values of the Language and Localizable properties of your form(s)? Have you tried "clean solution" and then "rebuild"? Is the resource dll updated in the output directory?

Comment: @pasty thanks for the reply. To set the `Text`, `ToolTip` etc. I use the designer; I select the button, then in the 'Properties' panel I edit the relevant property. In the 'bin\Debug' folder for example, I have all of the usual files including the 'de' and 'de-DE' folders which hold the resource DLLs. Currently the value of the 'Language' property is '(Default)' and the 'Localizable' is set to 'True'...

Comment: Then try this: set the desired properties through code (text, tooltip, etc.). Yes, it has some overhead, but then you use and set the text explicitely - button1.Text = ProjectResources.Translations.Hello; We have a project at work (the same constellation - separate project for resources) and it works error free (we are setting most of the translations in the code though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your build settings are wrong?
This is what I have for my dll.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The .resx file is attached to a WinForm. I have checked the properties and they all look right, all pointing to the correct file paths ect. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How do you switch cultures? Are you sure that is working in your release?

Comment: The files (.resx) contain the correct resource strings. They are UI resource files so are linked to a WinForm. These resources also show correctly in the designer. It is in release/debug at run-time that these resources appear erroneous like they are not being updated/compiled correctly...

Comment: Could you just create a small new project with one or two properties and see if it works there? And don't use the tool to translate the resx files, just do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

> I have given our translators software to allow them to edit the .resx files directly

That certainly was not a good idea.  Any professional translator will know how to tackle .NET resx files.  Even if they don't have any of the tooling that's traditionally used by translators, like SDL Passolo, then they would still fall back to the standard [Winres.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxdx003%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) included with the SDK.

Whatever you wrote probably has a bug.  Quite hard to reverse-engineer from the question what that bug might be.  Other than that the .resx file for a Winforms form is quite different from the one you get from Resource File project template or the resource designer.  There are lots of resource naming tricks to avoid ambiguity between the form's properties and the properties of its controls.  Get a name wrong and it won't work right.

Don't write your own, at least ask them to use Winres.exe if necessary.  It is free.

Comment: Hi Hans, the software I have provided is Zeta Resource Editor, a known piece of software that is equivalent to Winres.exe. What naming convention could cause this issue? Any resx has standard format, so I fail to see how allowing the forms .resx files to be edited via Winres/some other tool would be an issue. Thanks for your time...

Comment: I don't know, I've got nothing to look at.  Screenshots are not helpful to show the content of a .resx file.

Answer (score 1):

The bindings to the button are made in the Designer File of the related form, have you checked whether there are some issues? Try removing the code that sets the ressource and re-add it via the designer.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the .designer.cs file and this seems fine. All resources are being applied for these buttons. I will attempt to remove and re-add the controls...

Answer (score 0):

Probably this has something to do with the CopyLocal property. Please check if these are TRUE for these resource files. If not, set them to true, otherwise, after succesfull compilation, they are not being copied to the output directory.